# Dependent differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have been working with these differential equations that are dependent on each other:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= 0.1y-0.01(10000-a)\\
\frac{da}{dt} &= 0.1a-10y
\end{aligned}
$$
So the first equation represents the change rate of predatory fish while the other equation is a representation of small fish.

My question is: is there a way to find a general solution for these equations, say in form of an exponential function? And what does that factor 0.01 in the first equation stand for, having 10000 as the population of the small fish at the beginning?

Comment: one way to find a general solution is to (1) diagaonalize (if possible) the given system of equations or (2) differentiate the first equation and plug the second one into it and solve using exponentials...

Comment: Please check again your equations, if they are meant to be an instance of the most simple Volterra-Lotka predator-prey model, you are missing some grouping notations (parantheses). Perhaps there was also a division in the original formulation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did check the equations and, as you said, they seem to be some representation of the Volterra-Lotka model.

Comment: Note that Volterra-Lotka is non-linear, of the form $\dot y=yf(y,a)$, $\dot a=ag(y,a)$ so that the restriction to positive values in the exact solution is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the system in matrix form, introducing the vector $p:=(y,a)^T$. The system now reads

$$p'=Mp+q$$ where $M$ is a constant matrix and $q$ is a constant vector. We can get rid of $q$ by trying a contant solution $p_p$, such that

$$p_p'=0=Mp_p+q.$$ Then by subtraction,

$$p'=Mp.$$

Now assume a solution with an exponential form

$$p=ce^{\lambda t}.$$

We plug it in the equation and get

$$\lambda ce^{\lambda t}=Mce^{\lambda t},$$ or

$$Mc=\lambda c.$$

This shows that $\lambda$ is an Eigenvalue of $M$ and $c$ an Eigenvector. The general solution will combine the two Eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: I still didn't get to that level of using vectors in differential equations yet. I would appreciate it if you explain more, for instance using the example I mentioned!

Comment: @MrJava99: this is simple linear algebra. Rewrite with expliciting all elements of the matrix/vectors.

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = 0.1y - 0.01(10000-a)\space (1)$$
$$a' = 0.1a - 10y\space(2)$$

Differentiate (2) (since $a$ and $y$ differentiable):
$$a'' = 0.1a' - 10y'\implies y' = \frac{0.1a' - a''}{10}$$
Also from (2) you get:
$$y = \frac{0.1a - a'}{10}$$

Substitute those in (1) amd you get:
$$\frac{0.1a' - a''}{10} = 0.01(0.1a - a') - 0.001(10000 - a)\implies a'' - 0.2a'+0.011a = 10$$
which is a non-homogeneous second order ODE. Once you find $a$ you can find the solution $y$.

Comment: How did you get from y' = (0.1a'-a'')/10 to y = (0.1a-a')/10? Also is there a way to write formulas as you do?

Comment: @MrJava99 : To the last point, click on the edit link and study how mathjax/LaTeX formulas look in the source. Also available in the context menu "Show Math as > TeX commands".

Comment: @MrJava99 y = (0.1a-a')/10 comes from the equation indicated by the symbol (2)